# Excel - Create Dropdown list with unique entries and no 0 entries

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a named range called `sitelocation`, this it taking data from worksheet `sites` column B rows 10 - > 59

In Cell M10 I've added `=UNIQUE(sitelocation)`and that has produces the unique values from Column B, but it also contains a 0 entry.

If I make a names range as follows that doesn't contain the 0 entry, but does have duplicates.
`=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sites!$B$10"),0,0,COUNTA(Sites!$B:$B),1)`

I've tried wrapping that with UNIQUE, but it errors.
`=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sites!$B$10"),0,0,COUNTA(Sites!$B:$B),1)`

Ultimately I want to create a drop down list of unique values from Worksheet `Sites B10:B59`, with no 0 entries so I can use it on any worksheet in this workbook.

Can some one help.
Thanks

Comment: Nest `FILTER()`. >> `=UNIQUE(FILTER(Sites!B10:B59,Sites!B10:B59<>"","No Data"))`

Comment: @JvdV if I paste this into a cell it work, but I can't use it in name manager so I can apply it to another cell on a different worksheet.  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common formula for producing a unique list (and basing it in M10 as stated):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(sitelocation,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($M$9:M9,sitelocation),0)),"")
```

You can then copy this down and it will list all the unique values (including a `0` if it is in the list). However, you can move the `0` to the top of the list by placing the value `0` in M9 which is then referenced in the unique list formulae. If you take the values from cells M10 downwards, it won't contain `0` as that will always be in M9 so out of the list.

The named range for the list can then be assigned as:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$M$10,0,0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$M$10:$M$200,"?*"))
```

Comment: Thanks I got this working last night using a solution that is very similar to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FILTER inside and then UNIQUE outside:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(sitelocation, sitelocation>0, ""))
[Here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function) is a good description of FILTER.

Comment: If I paste this in to a cell it does show the unique entries, however I can't use it in a named list, so can't create a dropdown from it. Any ideas ?